# How do i run the charts in main dart? - flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to run charts from a library in flutter. I can't run in using main.dart.

Main.dart:

```
import './widgets/chart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: PointsLineChart(),
    ),
  );
}
```

chart.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class PointsLineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  PointsLineChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [LineChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory PointsLineChart.withSampleData() {
    return new PointsLineChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.LineChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(includePoints: true));
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 5),
      new LinearSales(1, 25),
      new LinearSales(2, 100),
      new LinearSales(3, 75),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample linear data type.
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

The error that i am getting is that in main.dart i need to input something in order to run chart.dart. In PointsLineChart(),

it gives me error:

1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.dart(not_enough_required_arguments)
(new) PointsLineChart(List> seriesList, {bool animate}) → PointsLineChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of PointsLineChart takes two argument:

```
PointsLineChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});
```

whereas in your main.dart, you give no arguments:

```
home: PointsLineChart(),// here you need to add two arguments!!!
```

Change the code as below:

```
runApp(
new MaterialApp(
  home: PointsLineChart(PointsLineChart.createSampleData(), animate: false),
),
```

);

also change _createSampleData to createSampleData to make it public.

[image]